# Does Nashorn (org.openjdk.nashorn) have any support for Java 17?

Tags: java, nashorn

I am trying to run an ANT build of our product using nashorn-core:15.1.1.jar with Java 17 (pre-release - build 27) and I get:

```
BUILD FAILED
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.openjdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context.compile(Context.java:1509)
    at org.openjdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context.compileScript(Context.java:1449)
    at org.openjdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context.compileScript(Context.java:759)
    at org.openjdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.compileImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:528)
    at org.openjdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.compileImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:517)
    at org.openjdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:395)
    at org.openjdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.eval(NashornScriptEngine.java:151)
    at java.scripting/javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:262)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.util.ReflectUtil.invoke(ReflectUtil.java:108)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.util.ReflectWrapper.invoke(ReflectWrapper.java:81)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.util.optional.JavaxScriptRunner.evaluateScript(JavaxScriptRunner.java:103)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.util.optional.JavaxScriptRunner.executeScript(JavaxScriptRunner.java:67)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.Script.execute(Script.java:52)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:811)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: no such method: sun.misc.Unsafe.defineAnonymousClass(Class,byte[],Object[])Class/invokeVirtual
    at org.openjdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context$AnonymousContextCodeInstaller.lambda$getDefineAnonymousClass$0(Context.java:335)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
    at org.openjdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context$AnonymousContextCodeInstaller.getDefineAnonymousClass(Context.java:327)
    at org.openjdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context$AnonymousContextCodeInstaller.<clinit>(Context.java:317)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: no such method: sun.misc.Unsafe.defineAnonymousClass(Class,byte[],Object[])Class/invokeVirtual
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MemberName.makeAccessException(MemberName.java:976)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolveOrFail(MemberName.java:1117)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.resolveOrFail(MethodHandles.java:3643)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.findVirtual(MethodHandles.java:2680)
    at org.openjdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context$AnonymousContextCodeInstaller.lambda$getDefineAnonymousClass$0(Context.java:329)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.Class sun.misc.Unsafe.defineAnonymousClass(java.lang.Class, byte[], java.lang.Object[])'
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.resolve(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolve(MemberName.java:1085)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolveOrFail(MemberName.java:1114)
    ... 39 more
```

I might be too early for being able to use Nashorn with Java 17, but figured I would check.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, [OpenJDK Nashorn](https://github.com/openjdk/nashorn) supports Java 17 starting with version 15.3.

It had to be adapted to [gracefully handle](https://github.com/openjdk/nashorn/pull/16) the fact `defineAnonymousClass` method was removed from the `Unsafe` class in Java 17.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, [support for Java Nashorn has been removed](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/372) from `Java 15` onwards and it is going to stay that way. It had been [deprecated](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/335) since `Java 11` onwards.

I suggest,if possible, migrating to [GraalVM JavaScript](https://www.graalvm.org/docs/getting-started/#run-javascript-and-nodejs) which is actively maintained. The main reason `Nashhorn` had been removed from `Java 15` onwards.

> The Nashorn JavaScript engine was first incorporated into JDK 8 via JEP 174 as a replacement for the Rhino scripting engine. When it was released, it was a complete implementation of the ECMAScript-262 5.1 standard.**With the rapid pace at which ECMAScript language constructs, along with APIs, are adapted and modified, we have found Nashorn challenging to maintain.**

Comment: Actually, there is an open source version of [Nashorn](https://github.com/openjdk/nashorn) that we have been using that was designed for Java 15+ (which was most recently recompiled at Java 11).  I am curious to know if anyone has tried using this and Java 17 with any success.  Otherwise, I will just follow the [GH issue steps](https://github.com/openjdk/nashorn#issue-tracking) for this project.

Comment: Just upgraded the JVM to 17, changed my imports and ran the JS test suites: all pass! Awesome, thanks for posting the link.